# How to do countdown in Dialog, and recover countdown if dialog is opened again

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, countdowntimer

I have a button, that opens a AlertDialog. Then, it starts a countdown, and refresh the text is inside the dialog:

```
private void countDown(int cooldown) {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(cooldown, COOLDOWN_TIME_STEP_MILLIS) { //sec , steps

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                isTimerActive = false;
                if (mFingerprintText != null) {
                    updateDialogText("Awsome text count: " + millisUntilFinished / COOLDOWN_TIME_STEP_MILLIS + " segs", false);
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                isTimerActive = false;
                if (mFingerprintText != null) {
                    updateDialogText("Awsome text count finished", false);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

But, if user close the dialiog and opens it again, I want to continue the countdown during the time passed. I mean, If I started the countdown at 13:00:00, (counts 1 min) , and user close at 13:00:15, if the user opens again , for example at: 13:00:30, I want to continue the count, so counter at this moments still have to count 30 more seconds...

I tried some different ways, but I'm not achieving it.

```
private void showTimerDialog(Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_request_android_timer, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        if (!isTimerActive) {
            mTimerText = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_timer_text);
        }

        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                if (mActive) {
                    deactivate();
                }
            }
        });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        mDialog = builder.create();
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create object of Dialog locally. Create a global variable in Activity. Now your Dialog creation and dismissal can be our or the method `showTimerDialog`

Override the Dialog's `AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE` and `AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE` .Call class methods to handle these scenarios

```
public class StartRaceFrag extends Activity{
//Keep a global instance
private AlertDialog mDialog;
//Create a boolean to check if timer already started or not
private boolean isTimerstarted;
```

Now in the method create object and push Dialog

```
    private void showTimerDialog(Context context) {
      //Start timer based on this bool variable
      if(!isTimerstarted){
        isTimerstarted=true;
      }
      final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
      View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_request_android_timer, null);

      builder.setView(dialogView);
      mDialog=builder.create();
      //Other dialog related statements
      //Override the Dialog Positive and Negative button and call other class methods to handle
```

Now based on this bool variable, you can modify method to run timer

```
private void countDown(int cooldown) {
   if(isTimerstarted){
     // Your business logic
   }else{
     //Handle for else case
   }
}
```